# Boundary conditions for Laplace's equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, boundary-conditions

Given a grounded conducting sphere, $V=0$ and $\text{radius} = R$, centered at the origin with a pure electric dipole (dipole moment $\vec p$) situated at the origin and pointing along the positive $z$ axis, I should be able to solve Laplace's equation in spherical coordinates to find the potential everywhere in the sphere. I can separate the differential equations and use Legendre polynomials, but I'm having trouble defining and using my boundary conditions. What I (think I) know so far:

$$V(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (A_n r^n + \frac{B_n}{r^{n+1}}) P_n(\cos{\theta})$$

$$r\to R \Rightarrow V\to 0$$
$$\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow V\to 0$$
$$\theta \to 0 \space or \space \pi \Rightarrow V\to \frac{\hat{r}\cdot \vec{p}}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r^2}$$

At least I think those boundary conditions work. I need to define a condition as well for the case of $$r \to 0$$
but that would seem to make the potential explode. How can I use these boundary conditions to solve for the potential everywhere inside the sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $r \to 0$, we know that the potential approaches $\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon _0} \frac{|\vec p|\cos{\theta}}{r^2}$.

Therefore(just by comparing the terms, which is usually the easiest method for solving these equations):

$$n \neq 1 \Rightarrow B_n = 0\\
B_1\ P_1 \left(\cos(\theta)\right)=B_1\ \cos\left(\theta \right)=\frac{p\ \cos\theta}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\\
B_1=\frac{p}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$$.

Now for $r=R$ we have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (A_n R^n ) P_n(\cos{\theta})+ \frac{B_1}{R^{2}} P_1(\cos{\theta})=0 \\
A_1 = -\frac{B_1}{R^3}, n \neq 1\Rightarrow A_n = 0$$

So the potential will be:

$$V\left(r,\theta \right)=\frac{p\cos(\theta)}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{r^2}-\frac{r}{R^3} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for responding! Can you elaborate why for $n \neq 1 \Rightarrow B_n = 0$?

Comment: @ArtM If they existed, as $r \to 0$ they would become more important than the first term we found.

Comment: Am I correct in asserting that adding a thin hollow spherical dielectric of radius $0<R'<R$would not change this solution, because the boundary conditions and total charge enclosed would not change?

Comment: @ArtM I think that will change the boundary condition I used, and replace it by something more complicated.

Comment: But $r\to R \Rightarrow V=0$ and $r\to 0 \Rightarrow V\to \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon _0} \frac{|\vec p|\cos{\theta}}{r^2}$ still apply. What other boundary condition was there?

Comment: I am doubting the second one.

Comment: How do I determine the last constant? This just gives me $A_1$ in terms of $B_1$.

Comment: Oh, that's easy. You can find it just by comparing the terms. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @Ali Why does $B_0=0$? For $B_n$ with $n > 1$ I get that they would be more significant than the $B_1$ term, but as $r \to 0$ $1/r^2$ will win over $1/r$, so how does this justify $B_0 = 0$? Thanks